# Is it possible to tell skrollr to ignore an attribute for the current data point?

Tags: skrollr

In the `data--50p` line I'd like to only specify the `opacity` property. The `top` property should be calculated using the values from `data--45` and `data--65` and ignore whatever is in the `data--50p` line.

Basically I am using `data--50p` to update only the `@show--video-btn` attribute.

```
data-0p-top="top[swing]: 150vh; @show--video-btn: !0;"
data--25p-top="top[swing]: 50vh; @show--video-btn: !1;"
data--45p-top="top[swing]: 50vh; @show--video-btn: !1;"
data--50p-top="top[swing]: Xvh; @show--video-btn: !2;"
data--65p-top="top[swing]: -130vh; @show--video-btn: !2;"
```

Is this possible? How?

I thought of calculating where the mid point be between `50vh` and `-130vh` but I am using `[swing]` so it's not a linear function and beyond my math abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if that is what you were asking, but you can make Scrollr ignore some css assignments by using *exclamaition mark* `!` in front of their values. See the "Preventing interpolation" section of the [Scrollr readme](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).

Comment: I am aware of the `!` option. What I am asking is: is it possible to have the `Xvh` value in `data--50p-top` get calculated between `50vh` and `-130vh` as if th `data--50p-top` entry did not exist?